# Obtaining the ids preceding and proceeding the queried id

Tags: php, mysql

I have a feature that gets the record for specific id and has two links for the previous and next record. Right now I have separate queries to obtain the next id:

```
$query = "SELECT id FROM presentations WHERE id > '$getId' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1";
```

$getId is the current id.

Is there a way to consolidate into one query?

Comment: Are they always going to be in sequential order? If not a separate relationship table will be needed to easily access prev/next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT A.id AS previd, B.id AS nextid 
FROM 
  (SELECT id FROM presentations WHERE id < '$getId' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) A,  
  (SELECT id FROM presentations WHERE id > '$getId' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1) B
```

Returns 2 columns: `previd` and `nextid` surrounding $getId

Comment: Which technically is now 3 queries, though I can't see any other way of doing this decently. So, +1

Comment: Note edit - I was missing the `DESC` modifier in the first `ORDER BY`

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use inner query

```
SELECT id FROM presentations 
WHERE id >= ( SELECT id FROM presentations WHERE id < '$getId' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0 , 1 ) 
ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0 , 3
```

first array result will be previous record, second will be your current record, and the last will be your last record.